# Why php function can't run with in my nginx?

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

PHP7 and nginx installed on centos7 this way.

To install php7

```
sudo  rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm   
sudo  yum install php70w  php70w-common
```

Now to check it with `php -v`.

```
PHP 7.0.19 (cli) (built: May 12 2017 21:01:27) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.19, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

To install nginx

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx
sudo systemctl enable nginx.service
```

To vim info.php in /usr/share/nginx/html.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

To input `vps_ip/info.php` , what i get is as below.

Why function phpinfo() can't execute?
Here is my nginx configuration file.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: nginx can't handle PHP. Please [read the documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx is a web server, not an application server. You need some you need some application server to interpret your php/ruby/python code.

Install `php-fpm`, in your case:

```
yum install php70w-fpm
```

and add to your server configuration following:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Which ensures that all files ending with `*.php` will be processed by `php-fpm` (FastCGI Process Manager for PHP). In this case listening on UNIX socket.

Make sure that `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` is configured to listen on socket:

```
;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
```

or just use TCP port in nginx server configuration:

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Finally restart both `nginx` and `php-fpm`:

```
systemctl restart php-fpm.service
systemctl restart nginx.service
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to install php-fpm and let nginx use it to handle php. Bad question, bad answer: read the documentation. Or at least find a good LEMP stack how to like this: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-nginx-with-php-and-mysql-lemp-stack-on-centos/

Comment: This guide also good https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7